# Missing var greek letters in math mode using eulervm

Tags: fonts, math-mode, letters, greek, eulervm

The `eulervm` package lacks the `varrho` and `varsigma` greek letters. Can I replace them by some greek letters from a different package? (So as that they rest distinct from their non-variant versions.)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}
Look at $\varrho$ and $\varsigma$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I wouldn't use `\rho` and `\varrho` with different meanings.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use default (i.e. Computer Modern) font of `\varrho` and `\varsigma`, you can declare using

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{greekletters}{OML}{cmr}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{greekletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{greekletters}{"26}
```

## Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{greekletters}{OML}{cmr}{m}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathalpha}{greekletters}{"25}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathalpha}{greekletters}{"26}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsfonts}

\begin{document}
Look at $\rho$ and $\sigma$

Look at $\varrho$ and $\varsigma$.
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Comment: How can I know that  the codes for \varrho and \varsigma as "25 and "26? In particular, in my case I also need \varphi and I would need its code. Thanks!